# python not always sending UDP message

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have following code

```
import socket
import time

MESSAGE1 = "SPD "
PERIOD = 1000*60
init_value = 0
update_value = 10000

sock.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

value=init_value

for i in range(6):
    value = value + update_value
    MESSAGE = MESSAGE1 + str(value)
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE.encode(),("10.10.10.10",12345))

    time.sleep(int(PERIOD)/1000.0)
```

The issue is that I don't always see the message sent out (in Wireshark I don't see the message). Any suggestion what could be done to solve the issue?

Comment: I edited your code to properly create the socket. I also changed the IP address (in my local version) to make sense for my local environment. After doing so, your code works fine for me on my Linux box. There must be something else in your environment going on. Sending one datagram every 60 seconds as you're doing shouldn't be stressing anything and should be pretty dependable -- at least on the sending end -- you never know what might get lost in transit with UDP but if you're running wireshark on the same box or on the next hop, you should be seeing the packet.

Comment: @GilHamilton Don't do that. Answer the question by exhibiting the error and its correction, You have just made the presence of this question here completely pointless. Rolled back.

Comment: Are you running Wireshark on the sending computer, or on the receiving computer (or both)?

Comment: @user207421 The correction I made was trivial and almost certainly a copy-paste error. It made no significant change in the clear intent of the code logic, and based on OP's question was not responsible for the original issue OP was seeing. Rolling it back was persnickety at best.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running Python under `strace` to see which system calls are executed under the hood and if they fail. If they succeed, then the problem is not with Python, but in the network configuration. On Linux it could be the firewall (`iptables`) or traffic control layer.